# Find time durations for log entries for each date, conditions (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, logging, time, timestamp, duration

I have a column of time stamped log entries. For each date i need to pull the duration from the first entry that day to the last entry for that day. Ideally, any duration between log entries more than one hour would would not be included in the total time.

There are also instances where the dates and times are not in order due to an edit which creates a new time stamp in the log but the row remains in the same place.

This is a log of shipments scanned in/out of inventory. We use it to track efficiency.

```
Entry Time Stamp
8/29/2022 8:52:17
8/29/2022 9:13:59
8/29/2022 9:14:03
8/29/2022 9:52:16
8/29/2022 10:45:36
8/29/2022 10:46:05
**8/29/2022 11:27:00
8/29/2022 11:36:53
8/29/2022 11:30:05**
8/29/2022 12:14:44
8/29/2022 12:16:07
8/29/2022 12:53:42
8/29/2022 12:54:51
8/29/2022 13:00:32
8/29/2022 13:19:10
8/30/2022 10:45:51
8/30/2022 10:54:41
8/30/2022 11:23:07
8/30/2022 12:16:05
8/30/2022 12:43:44
8/30/2022 12:54:22
**8/30/2022 12:55:27
8/30/2022 14:01:29**
8/30/2022 14:39:18
8/30/2022 15:08:43
8/31/2022 9:16:35
8/31/2022 9:43:28
8/31/2022 9:46:05
8/31/2022 9:48:01
8/31/2022 10:40:08
8/31/2022 11:08:59
8/31/2022 11:14:31
9/1/2022 10:51:19
9/1/2022 11:16:09
9/1/2022 11:17:07
9/1/2022 11:59:28
9/1/2022 12:01:48
9/1/2022 12:05:31
9/1/2022 12:07:20
9/1/2022 12:08:59
9/1/2022 12:10:30
9/1/2022 12:11:42
9/1/2022 12:22:05
```

[snip of the spreadsheet column; in bold are the random time stamp issues, non sequential entry and duration between log entries more than one hour]

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

### Arrayformula option

**01 - Duration** Use this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,VLOOKUP(IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,DAY(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1))),QUERY(sortn(sort({SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1),
               
               IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,DAY(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)))},1,TRUE),9^9,2,2,true), "Select Col2,Col1"),2,1))="",,SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)-IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,VLOOKUP(IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,DAY(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1))),QUERY(sortn(sort({SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1),
               
               IF(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)="",,DAY(SORT(IF(A2:A="",,
               DATEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col1")) 
             + TIMEVALUE( QUERY(TRIM( SPLIT(TEXT(IF(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"\*")<>TRUE,A2:A),A2:A,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\*","")), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), " ")), "Select Col2"))),1,1)))},1,TRUE),9^9,2,2,true), "Select Col2,Col1"),2,1))))
```

[image]

---

**02 - Total duration less than 1 hour** Use this formula

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<(1/24)))
```

[image]

---

**03 -** if you want to get **Total duration for duration between log entries Less than one hour** Use this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(FILTER(B2:B,(B3:B-B2:B)<(1/24))))
```

[image]